# Trying to write a macro that will quickly fill in the monthly rates of a hotel using data from 2 ranges (rate & corresponding seasons)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

[How it looks before monthly data entered]
[image]

[How it should look if the macro works correctly]
[image]

```
For seasoncolumn = 30 To 34
    Cells(42, seasoncolumn).Value = season
    
    For rows = 42 To 1300
        For months = 35 To 35 + season
            Cells(rows, months).Value = rate
        Next months
    Next rows
Next seasoncolumn
```

Any help or ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of linking an image to your data you can use [this site](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to generate the markdown tables and insert them into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate your seasons count to match the month number. You also need to grab the matching rate number from your season number.

You haven't provided us with a sample worksheet so I don't know where your data is on the sheet. I've put some constants in the code below which you'll need to change to grab your target cells. The basic handling code comes below these constants:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim rates() As Variant
Dim seaons() As Variant
Dim months() As Variant
Dim r As Long, m As Long, s As Long, agg As Long

Const HEADER_ROW As Long = 1 'row containing headers.
Const RATES_FIRST_COL As String = "A" 'first column of rates
Const SEASONS_FIRST_COL As String = "F" 'first column of seasons
Const MONTHS_FIRST_COL As String = "K" 'first column of months
Const RATES_AND_SEAONS_COUNT As Long = 5

With Sheet1
    lastRow = Sheet1.Range(RATES_FIRST_COL & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    rates = .Range(RATES_FIRST_COL & HEADER_ROW & ":" & RATES_FIRST_COL & lastRow).Resize(, RATES_AND_SEAONS_COUNT).Value
    seaons = .Range(SEASONS_FIRST_COL & HEADER_ROW & ":" & SEASONS_FIRST_COL & lastRow).Resize(, RATES_AND_SEAONS_COUNT).Value
    months = .Range(MONTHS_FIRST_COL & HEADER_ROW & ":" & MONTHS_FIRST_COL & lastRow).Resize(, 12).Value
End With

For r = 2 To UBound(rates, 1) ' start from 2 as 1 contains the headers
    s = 1
    agg = seaons(r, s)
    For m = 1 To 12
        If m > agg Then
            s = s + 1
            agg = agg + seaons(r, s)
        End If
    months(r, m) = rates(r, s)
    Next
Next

With Sheet1
    .Range(MONTHS_FIRST_COL & HEADER_ROW & ":" & MONTHS_FIRST_COL & lastRow).Resize(, 12).Value = months
End With
```

Comment: The code you gave me is awesome and a much better way to do what I was trying to do.  I substituted my columns in the constants and ran the code, but I get a "Subscript out of Range" error at "agg = agg + seaons(r,s)" and I can't figure out why.  I'm having trouble understanding what the "For" loop part of the code is doing so I'm having issues troubleshooting. Thank you for your help....if you have any more suggestions, please by all means :)

Comment: Check that your seasons values add up to 12. The error is likely because the s value has gone beyond 5.

Comment: So finally got it working :)  Had to add "And s < 5" to the "For m  = 1 To 12"  If statement so it would stop looping before s got to 6.  You're a genius Ambie!!!  Thank you so much for your help!!  Taught me so much about holding arrays in VBA!  Thank you!